# Couchbase multiple buckets in .NET app.config

Tags: .net, app-config, couchbase

Couchbase .Net manual says that I can configure my client in this way:

```
<couchbase><servers bucket="default" bucketPassword="">
  <add uri="http://192.168.0.2:8091/pools/default"/>
  <add uri="http://192.168.0.3:8091/pools/default"/>
</servers></couchbase>
```

Is there any way to define sevral buckets in app.config and then switch between them in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to John's suggestion, I used such configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="couchbase">
      <section name="bucket-1" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase"/>
      ...
      <section name="bucket-N" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  ...
  <couchbase>
    <bucket-1>
      <servers bucket="bucket-1" bucketPassword="pass">
        <add uri="http://10.0.0.1:8091/pools/default"/>
        <add uri="http://10.0.0.2:8091/pools/default"/>
      </servers>
    </bucket-1>
  </couchbase>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Then in app code you can get bucket's client:

```
var client = new CouchbaseClient((CouchbaseClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("couchbase/bucket-1"));
```

It would be nice, if developers of .Net couchbase library implement reading such configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around for the above issue.

We can use the CouchbaseClient constructor overload and pass in the bucketname and password.
Ex: var client = new CouchbaseClient("default","");

It is not needed to put all bucket config's in the app or web.cong files.

Comment: Suggested alternative in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600486/multiple-couchbase-bucket-configuration-in-net/10645617#10645617

Comment: Yes. I use this solution (I've created a dictionary of buckets for myself Dictionary(<bucketnames>,<CouchbaseClientConfiguration>)), but in this way buckets are "hardcoded". Now I'm thinking about writing own xml-file with buckets config and then parse it.