# Couchbase memcached bucket on multiple hosts not getting all results

Tags: c#, memcached, couchbase

I am using a couchbase memcached bucket as a replacement to our older memcached cache.
I also have a couchbase bucket on the same cluster.

The cluster has two nodes and the configuration I have used is pretty basic.

```
<couchbase>
    <CouchBaseBucket>
      <servers bucket="CouchBaseBucket" bucketPassword="password">
        <add uri="http://10.100.10.97:8091/pools"/>
        <add uri="http://10.100.10.98:8091/pools"/>
      </servers>
    </CouchBaseBucket>
    <MemcachedBucket>
      <servers bucket="MemcachedBucket" bucketPassword="password">
        <add uri="http://10.100.10.97:8091/pools"/>
        <add uri="http://10.100.10.98:8091/pools"/>
      </servers>
    </MemcachedBucket>    
  </couchbase>
```

(the multi-bucket configuration was done according to the SO post here [Couchbase multiple buckets in .NET app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554175/couchbase-multiple-buckets-in-net-app-config))

The problem is that I do not always get a cache hit for entries I just inserted (but sometimes I do). The whole bucket has a mere 4-5 items out of 2 available GBs and the key-value pair consists of a 20-char key and a Guid value, so eviction should not be an issue.

When I tried this in a test setup with just one host, I never had this issue, so I have a suspicion that this might have to do with the NodeLocator, which however should be the default KetamaNodeLocator as I am not defining something else in the configuration.

The client I am using is the Couchbase .NET client library, Assembly version 1.1.6.0 and my server is couchbase server 1.8.1

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, nothing to do with multiple hosts.
Well... almost.

The problem was that one of the hosts' clock was off by two hours in the future. #omg

I think this is a problem for Couchbase though, as it assumes/requires that all the servers involved (those running the server and those running the clients) must have their clocks synced.

Anyway, maybe this will save some poor soul some hours of investigation